# How to make a numpy calculation between two metrices on all combinations of columns?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, vision

I have the following attempt to calculate IOU for several detections I get from a face detector.

```
import numpy as np


class BboxUtils(object):
    @staticmethod
    def ious(bboxes1, bboxes2):
        left1, top1, right1, bottom1 = BboxUtils.bbox_to_perimiters(bboxes1)
        left2, top2, right2, bottom2 = BboxUtils.bbox_to_perimiters(bboxes2)

        area1 = (right1 - left1) * (top1 - bottom1)
        area2 = (right2 - left2) * (top2 - bottom2)

        intersection_left = np.maximum(left1, left2)
        intersection_right = np.minimum(right1, right2)
        intersection_top = np.maximum(top1, top2)
        intersection_bottom = np.minimum(bottom1, bottom2)
        intersection_area = (intersection_right - intersection_left) * (intersection_top - intersection_bottom)
        intersection_area[intersection_area < 0] = 0

        iou = intersection_area / (area1 + area2 - intersection_area)

        return iou

    @staticmethod
    def bbox_to_perimiters(bboxes):
        left, w, top, h = np.split(bboxes.reshape(-1), 4)
        right = left + w
        bottom = top + h
        return left, right, top, bottom


# example usage:
detections1 = my_detector.detect(frame1) #np.array of shape (n1, 4)
detections2 = my_detector.detect(frame2) #np.array of shape (n2, 4)
ious = BboxUtils.ious(detections1, detections2)
```

This code assumes that:

1. The detections on the 2 frames (`bboxes1` and `bboxes2`) are of the
   same length
2. Each detection's index is the same in `bboxes1` and `bboxes2`

I would like to calculate IOU with the same logic as the code above, but *avoid for loops*.

Notice `bboxes1` and `bboxes2` can be matrices of shape `(n1, 4)` and `(n2, 4)`, where `n1` is not necessarily equal `n2`.

How can this be done?

Finally, probably there is a library that does all that already. 
Please refer me if it does exist.

Comment: How `my_detector.detect` is defined?

Comment: @V.Ayrat it returns a np.array (n, 4). you can assume `np.random.rand(np.random.randint(10), 4)`

Comment: It works right if `n1 == n2`, you want to make it work if `n1 != n2`?

Comment: @V.Ayrat It only works if `n1==n2` and the indices of the original detections are the same. Here also assume `detections1  = np.random.shuffle(detections1)`, as the detector can't know about ordering.

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You write "avoid for loops" - there is no for loops in your code. If you want it works if `n1 != n2` - what should happens in this case? Now you code take 10 pairs of rectangles and calculate the intersections of them pairwise. I don't understand how you define this if there is say 10 rectangles and 20 rectangles?